# Java pula meu scanner e não me deixa responder!

Tags: java, scanner

Estou aprendendo Java sozinho. Uma das atividades era a seguinte:

> "Faça um programa que funcione como uma calculadora entre dois números
> quaisquer, que permita escolher calcular a soma, subtração, divisão ou
> multiplicação entre eles."

Meu código é esse aqui:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class teste01{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);

        int num1=0, num2=0;
        String operacao="";

        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro número:");
        num1=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o segundo número:");
        num2=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Qual operação deseja realizar?");
        operacao=scan.next();
        
        if (operacao=="soma" ||operacao=="+") {
            System.out.println(num1+num2);
        }else if (operacao=="subtracao" || operacao=="-"){
            System.out.println(num1-num2);
        }else if(operacao=="divisao" || operacao=="/"){
            System.out.println(num1/num2);
        }else if (operacao=="multiplicacao" || operacao=="*"){
            System.out.println(num1*num2);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Esta opção não é válida, tente novamente.");
        }
        


    }
}
```

Porém, sempre que chega na parte de perguntar qual operação deseja realizar, eu respondo soma por exemplo e mesmo assim ele me retorna "Esta opção não é válida, tente novamente.". Podem me ajudar a entender o que está errado?
É a minha primeira pergunta aqui na comunidade, eu utilizo o VS Code, já fiz atividades similares utilizando o Scanner e todas funcionaram. Já passei umas 2 horas tentando entender onde está meu erro. Obrigado!

Comment: Utilize o método  `equals` para fazer comparações com `string` em Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em java se você comparar o valor de uma variavel String e um valor literal(mesmo sendo uma string entre aspas) com "==" ele retorna falso, por isso ele pula direto para o ultimo else, quando todos os outros dão falso. Para comparar valor literal com variável string vc usa o "equals(String)". No caso seu código ficaria:

```
        if (operacao.equals("soma") || operacao.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(num1+num2);
        }else if (operacao.equals("subtracao") || operacao.equals("-")){
            System.out.println(num1-num2);
        }else if(operacao.equals("divisao") || operacao.equals("/")){
            System.out.println(num1/num2);
        }else if (operacao.equals("multiplicacao") || operacao.equals("*")){
            System.out.println(num1*num2);
```

testa ai

Comment: Perfeito amigo, resolveu corretamente o problema, obrigado pela atenção!